# Center (vertically) a span element

Tags: html, css

I have a span inside a div and I'm trying to center it (i.e. I want the text [why learn music]inside the span to be directly in the centre (both horizontally and vertically) of the div. Vertical-align is not working so far. 
Attached is a picture of the current status of the text. JS Fiddle:

`<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/Cheetaiean/qzd8k9uf/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Picture:
[image: picture of page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and added the follow to the text or the span

```
margin-top:-350px;
```

it works fine, it will work for you, if not then change the span to be a div and add the same margin top to minus value and you are done

Comment: Changed the span to a div and then used margin-top 10%  to text and it worked... Thanks! I assume spans just have weird properties that I'm not aware of lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a fake image:

```
<img width="0" height="the height of the container div" align="middle" />
```

That should do.

Answer (score 0):

You may use flexbox.

```
div {display:flex; justify-content:center;} /*vertical align*/

span {align-self:center;} /*horizontal align*/
```

This positions your span right in the middle of your div.